# Spell sniper / self cast spells

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

So with spell sniper could it make say burning hands not self cast  or anything other self cast spell not have to be self cast?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Spell Sniper tells you what it does. Are you asking if Spell Sniper changes the range of a spell with a regular range of "Self"? (If so, what do you think it would be changing the range to?)

Comment: My bad it not attack roll spell

Comment: If the attack roll portion clears it up, you could probably press the check mark next to Darth Pseudonym's answer to mark that it is the correct one.

Answer (score 5):

No, feats are very clear and specific about what they do. Spell Sniper increases the range of spells that have *attack rolls*, and allows ranged spells to ignore cover. Most "self" spells don't have an attack roll anyway (such as *burning hands*, which makes the targets roll saves instead), but spells with a range of touch or self are not altered even if they do have attack rolls, because "touch" and "self" are not numbers that can be doubled.

There are effects in the game that do allow you to use some of those spells at range, such as the Sorcerer's "Distant Spell" metamagic, but they will say exactly how they work.